# C++ Calling an external exe - not passing arguments

Tags: c++

So I am making a small service that has 2 different programs.

Program 1.exe is the service and loops through using recvfrom waiting for a connection. Once a packet is received, I create a string to send to Program 2.
Program 2.exe is called by Program 1. It takes a single argument then does some stuff using the argument then sends a UDP packet back to the client.

Now I am having a problem where I can't seem to get arguments to be passed to Program 2. It calls Program 2, I can see the process and I have an output to a text file that it is running the code. But when I check to see if it has the arguments, they are coming up blank. I was trying to pass a string to them but then decided to just try and hardcode some arguments into it but it still doesn't pass them. There is the process code in question:

```
        STARTUPINFO si;
        PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

        ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si));
        si.cb = sizeof(si);
        ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(pi));

        // Start the child process. 
        if (!CreateProcess(_T("C:\\Stats-Server.exe"),   // No module name (use command line)
            _T("172.30.4.1:diskspace:c"),        // Command line
            NULL,           // Process handle not inheritable
            NULL,           // Thread handle not inheritable
            FALSE,          // Set handle inheritance to FALSE
            0,              // No creation flags
            NULL,           // Use parent's environment block
            NULL,           // Use parent's starting directory 
            &si,            // Pointer to STARTUPINFO structure
            &pi)           // Pointer to PROCESS_INFORMATION structure
            )
        {
            printf("CreateProcess failed (%d).\n", GetLastError());
            return 0;
        }

        // Wait until child process exits.
        WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, INFINITE);

        // Close process and thread handles. 
        CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
        CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
```

I've tried putting LPTSTR infront of the command and arguments but it still just launches the exe without arguments. What could be going wrong?

Comment: If you wait anyway, might I ask why you don't simply go with a call of `std::system`?

Comment: In the end I am not going to get it to wait. I am just going to start the process and then loop for another recvfrom.

Answer (score 0):

A space... a bloody space. I simplified it a little.

```
        TCHAR* path = L"C:\\Stats-Server.exe";
        TCHAR* arr = L" 172.30.4.1:diskspace:c";

        STARTUPINFO info;
        PROCESS_INFORMATION processInfo;

        ZeroMemory(&info, sizeof(info));
        info.cb = sizeof(info);
        ZeroMemory(&processInfo, sizeof(processInfo));


        if (CreateProcess(path, arr, NULL, NULL, TRUE, 0, NULL, NULL, &info, &processInfo))
        {
            ::WaitForSingleObject(processInfo.hProcess, INFINITE);
            CloseHandle(processInfo.hProcess);
            CloseHandle(processInfo.hThread);
        }
```

Now all I need to do is work out how to get my std::string message into the function.

Answer (score 0):

The commandline typically includes the actual command too: `_T("\"C:\\Stats-Server.exe\" 172.30.4.1:diskspace:c")`.

You could create a helper class for building the command line. Example:

```cpp
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>

template<class CharT>
class CommandLineBuilder {
public:
    using String = std::basic_string<CharT>;

    template<class App, class... Args>
    CommandLineBuilder(App&& app, Args&&... args) :
        // put all the arguments in the vector
        data({std::forward<App>(app), std::forward<Args>(args)...}) 
    {}

    const String& AppName() const {
        // return a const& to the application/module name
        return data[0];
    }

    String CmdLine() const {
        // build the command line string - enclose each arg with double quotes
        String rv;
        if constexpr (std::is_same_v<CharT, wchar_t>)
            rv = L'"' + data[0] + L'"';
        else
            rv = '"' + data[0] + '"';

        for(size_t idx = 1; idx < data.size(); ++idx) {
            if constexpr (std::is_same_v<CharT, wchar_t>)
                rv += L" \"" + data[idx] + L'"';
            else
                rv += " \"" + data[idx] + '"';
        }
        return rv;
    }

private:
    std::vector<String> data;
};

// C++17 deduction guides:
template<template<class, class...> class C, class CharT, class..., class... Args>
CommandLineBuilder(const C<CharT>&, Args&&...) -> CommandLineBuilder<CharT>;

template<class App, class... Args, std::enable_if_t<std::is_pointer_v<App>, int> = 0>
CommandLineBuilder(App, Args&&...) ->
    CommandLineBuilder<std::remove_const_t<std::remove_pointer_t<std::decay_t<App>>>>;
```

You could then use it to simplify calling `CreateProcess`:

```cpp
CommandLineBuilder cmd(_T("C:\\Stats-Server.exe"),
                       _T("172.30.4.1:diskspace:c"));

if (!CreateProcess(cmd.AppName().c_str(), 
                   cmd.CmdLine().data(),
                   ...))  // the rest of the arguments
{
    ...
```